# GET request for receiving the parameter from android in spring REST API?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to write the spring REST code to get the parameters  send by the android users. For example android users fills out the form and click send button. Now I want to receive the values or parameters in REST API. I search google but could not figure out how to do it. Below is the code I tried but it didn't work

*EmailController.java*

```
package com.intern.training


import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/email")
public class EmailController
{

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getAll(WebRequest webRequest)
    {
        Map<String,String[]>params=webRequest.getParameterMap();
        System.out.println(params);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advice you to not send parameters with a `GET` request. Prefer a `POST` request. (See [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery))

Then, create a class which represents the parameters that you are to receive :

```
public class RequestParams {

  private String name;
  private String surname;

  //Getters, Setters...

}
```

Then expect this object as a param of your method :

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
/**
   Pay attention to the above @RequestBody annotation 
   or you will get null instead of the parameters
**/
public void getAll(@RequestBody RequestParams request)
{
    request.getName();
    request.getSurname();
    //...
    System.out.println(request.getName() + " " + request.getSurname());
}
```

Comment: But how it will receive the parameters from android

Comment: suppose the name and surname is parameter send by android form then how to receive it in spring

Comment: @programmingtech Android can send POST request. If you really want, you can accept request params (see @ RequestParam binding) but I strongly advise you to avoid using it with potentially destructive requests.

Comment: what if the android user sending the JSON object